# Obtain a key value from another key's value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I am trying to parse a [Netscape HTTP Cooke File](http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html) used by the PHP `curl` function.

I'm using [this parser](http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/netscape-http-cooke-file-parser-php) that returns an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [domain] => REDACTED
            [flag] => FALSE
            [path] => /
            [secure] => FALSE
            [expiration] => 2016-05-23 03:27:19
            [name] => csrftoken
            [value] => REDACTED
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [domain] => #HttpOnly_REDACTED
            [flag] => FALSE
            [path] => /
            [secure] => FALSE
            [expiration] => 2015-06-08 03:27:17
            [name] => sessionid
            [value] => REDACTED
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [domain] => REDACTED
            [flag] => FALSE
            [path] => /
            [secure] => FALSE
            [expiration] => 1969-12-31 09:00:00
            [name] => PHPSESSID
            [value] => REDACTED
        )

)
```

I need to obtain the `sessionid` here. The problem is, I can't just use $array[1]['value'], because the number of arrays and their position isn't fixed. All I know for sure is $array[?]['name'] == "sessionid".

Comment: I would redesign how you create these arrays then. Keys are designed to be the things you **know**.

Comment: Then just go with `$array[1]['key2b']` to get `value2b`. I don't know what's your problem/question right now.

Comment: the question is not that clear for me. Can't get what u exactly want. If you can give us what's the desired output you want then it will help to understand much better

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
<?php

// this is array returned to you from parser
$array = ...;

foreach ($array as $number => $row) {
    if ($row['name'] == 'sessionid') {
        $index = $number;
        break;
    }        
}

if (isset($number)) {
    $sessionID = $array[$index];
} else {
    echo "nothing found";
}

// now you can use $sessionID['expiration'] etc
```

Comment: `$sessionID = $array[$index]['value']` works for me :D

Comment: Is there any shorter way of doing that using a native function?